# where is the model and controoler page of shipping.phtml page in magento

Tags: magento

i am new in magento. i haven't understand the the MVC structure of Magento.
where can i get the Model & Controller pager of shipping.phtml page.
shipping.phtml page is in the

```
app>design>frontend>base>default>template>checkout>cart>shipping.phtml
```

Comment: enable the template path hints to find the locations of the file

Answer (score 0):

you can find controller under the following directory for controller
app/code/core/mage/checkout/controllers/onepagecontroller.php

Answer (score 0):

Magento create view for single request by merging many blocks. Here `shipping.phtml` is Child Block for Cart page. You can get more understanding for Child block used in Cart page by checking `<checkout_cart_index>` handler in `checkout.xml`.

As per your question "where can i get the Model & Controller pager of shipping.phtml page". There is no controller for shipping.phtml. For the cart Page contoller is as follows:
`app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php`

For the cart page Model is as follows: 
`app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php`

In Magento every `.phtml` file related to Block. As 'shipping.phtml' is a template file. Related template for this block is as follows: 
`app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping.php`